# Replace NTFS Permissions with PowerShell

Tags: permissions, powershell-3.0, ntfs

I'm working with a fileserver that was connected to an old domain a few years ago. For some reason, the old domain is now gone and replaced by a new one. The only problem is that there are still some NTFS Permissions that uses the old users, of the old domain (OLDDOMAIN\User).

I Want to replace these permissions with the users on the new domein (NEWDOMAIN\User). Every user on the old domain has the same user on the new domain.

Is there a way to do this with powershell, or maybe an other way? I've already tried 'NTFSSecurity (https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1abd77a5-9c0b-4a2b-acef-90dbb2b84e85), but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this question rather belongs to Server Fault, but I'd use ADMT (Active Directory Migration Tool, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974332%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).